# How to deserialize JSON in C# using javascript deserialize (not using newtonsoft)?

Tags: c#, json, serialization, deserialization, json-deserialization

I want to parse a JSON using javascript deserializer in C#. JSON is given below:

```
{
  "Friends": {
    "123": {
        "PKey": ["Password"],
        "hasParent": 0
    },
    "456": {
        "PKey": ["Maximum"],
      "hasParent": 0
    }


    },

"NotFriends": {
    "789": {
      "PKey": {
        "Sec": [
          "User"
        ],
        "Reg": []
      },
      "hasParent": 0
    }
}
    }
```

what are the classes and functions used in parsing such JSON?

Comment: You tagged the relevant class: `JavaScriptSerializer`.  Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

1. First, create correspondence Model Class for JSON data in C# with same name & fields.
2. Use JavaScriptSerializer: It will direct serialize JSON data into the model.

   ```
   var response = "JSON String";

   //If list model 
   var objectModelList = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<List<YourModelClass>>(response).ToList();

   //If class model
   var objectModel = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<YourModelClass>(response);
   ```